# PACF for Airline Passengers dataset: What's wrong?

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, pacf

The airline passengers dataset is available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/chirag19/air-passengers), but it also comes with in R.

I'm working with python, and I import the following (besides the usual like pandas and numpy.)

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf,acf
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller,kpss
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from scipy import stats
```

I'm applied the log, and then 1-period difference for detrending , and then 12-period for 'deseasonality'. Then I drop the nan, with `df_log_dif_dif12.dropna(inplace=True)`.

I obtain the following numpy array:

```
array([[ 0.03916403],
       [ 0.00036069],
       [-0.02049559],
       [-0.01293918],
       [ 0.06614834],
       [ 0.03991464],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.01135398],
       [-0.03871451],
       [-0.01941809],
       [ 0.07915025],
       [ 0.06084382],
       [-0.05744823],
       [ 0.05867027],
       [-0.04454824],
       [ 0.13070532],
       [-0.1413435 ],
       [-0.02033086],
       [ 0.        ],
       [-0.00516566],
       [ 0.04490648],
       [ 0.05016097],
       [-0.07706281],
       [-0.00541555],
       [ 0.01739174],
       [-0.10141492],
       [ 0.02384019],
       [-0.04275515],
       [ 0.14071984],
       [-0.05793703],
       [ 0.05085842],
       [-0.06823441],
       [ 0.0372786 ],
       [-0.00078924],
       [-0.00801748],
       [-0.01941927],
       [-0.05129329],
       [ 0.11598381],
       [ 0.05994687],
       [-0.03685263],
       [-0.11566947],
       [ 0.02930341],
       [-0.02100545],
       [ 0.00886155],
       [-0.02614118],
       [-0.05412233],
       [-0.01001563],
       [ 0.00455859],
       [-0.08167803],
       [ 0.03742641],
       [-0.03038921],
       [ 0.05623461],
       [ 0.06128855],
       [ 0.05159025],
       [-0.06010737],
       [ 0.01439738],
       [-0.00690405],
       [ 0.03838526],
       [ 0.01016797],
       [ 0.04040064],
       [ 0.04377876],
       [-0.08693335],
       [ 0.04209822],
       [-0.02666052],
       [ 0.03352269],
       [ 0.01010331],
       [-0.01757468],
       [ 0.01702296],
       [-0.00676902],
       [-0.02455194],
       [ 0.03904495],
       [-0.0338626 ],
       [ 0.01294254],
       [-0.00132594],
       [-0.0201613 ],
       [ 0.01213761],
       [ 0.00805373],
       [-0.04538943],
       [ 0.02826856],
       [-0.02544769],
       [-0.01865761],
       [ 0.02360168],
       [-0.03809469],
       [ 0.00763441],
       [-0.02050564],
       [ 0.0329362 ],
       [-0.01002967],
       [ 0.00406712],
       [ 0.01068311],
       [-0.0021597 ],
       [ 0.02385238],
       [-0.0131451 ],
       [-0.00355741],
       [-0.00754672],
       [-0.0246669 ],
       [-0.01715308],
       [-0.02143186],
       [-0.03822764],
       [-0.01671348],
       [ 0.02228504],
       [ 0.00805567],
       [ 0.02406601],
       [ 0.02382245],
       [-0.07822917],
       [ 0.03399761],
       [-0.01773709],
       [-0.01328875],
       [ 0.05418664],
       [ 0.01560094],
       [ 0.04194959],
       [ 0.01450278],
       [ 0.01664015],
       [-0.06421892],
       [ 0.0281982 ],
       [-0.00824012],
       [ 0.03472113],
       [-0.01082138],
       [ 0.02958112],
       [ 0.02873222],
       [-0.03682195],
       [-0.01308537],
       [-0.10237906],
       [ 0.12046607],
       [-0.03525956],
       [ 0.00856349],
       [ 0.00137704],
       [-0.04593429],
       [ 0.01202388],
       [ 0.03183046],
       [-0.05008233],
       [-0.00996401]])
```

Now, when I run

```
partial_acf_log=pacf(df_log_dif_dif12,nlags=df_log_dif_dif12.shape[0] // 2 - 1)
tsaplots.plot_pacf(partial_acf_log,lags=len(partial_acf_log)//2-1);
```

I get the following picture:

[image]

This picture is nothing like the one in the book by Shumway and Stoffer Time Series Analysis.

[image]

In my graph, I see no significant peaks, whereas in the graph from the book, we can see significant peaks for lags 1, and multiples of 12... The strangest thing was when I first ran the plot, it showed something much similar to the book. But, when I ran it for the second time, the plot changed completely. Not only that, I don't even get to have enough data to compute lags of size 35, 40... But in the book, the authors are able.

P.S.: Just for comparison here's a picture of the transformed, detrended and deseasonalised data in the book.

[image]

It's equal to the plot you get from the array above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it happens that tsaplots.plot_pacf already computes the pacf. So, what I was running was the pacf of the pacf values...

Instead, I should have simply run tsaplots.plot_pacf on the original data.

Here's the correct graph.

[image]